# from applicationWillEnterForeground:method get UIButton text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I tried to get the UIbutton currentTile/titleLabel from applicationWillEnterForeground:method.It gives the same even i change the text.

Comment: We will need more than that. do you have a valid handle to the UIButton object. Where is the object declared?

Comment: You put some code of your thats will more explanation for us.

Comment: i have declared the UIButton in viewController.h and assign the value in viewContrller.m. Now i want to access the button title from AppDeligate.m method applicationWillEnterForeground:method.

Comment: in viewControler.m:   - (void)viewDidLoad
{   Button.Titlelabel.text=@"Trichy";}       in AppDelegate.m : - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{Nslog(@"%@",self.viewController.Button.Titlelabel.text);}  This work correct but i change the title of UIButton dinamically. it shows the same title name when i set first time.  Thanks for quick replay

Answer (score 0):

you better save the title of the UIButton as a datamember and try to get the title in applicationWillEnterForeground method.

Comment: i am new to Xcode. can you say how to assign the title into datamember.i have tried to create the Nsstring in viewController.h and assign title but it shows null in the AppDelegate method.

Comment: hi thanks to replay please give any example to create datamemmber and assign.which is should done in AppDelegate/viewController.